# Show list of product variations with price behind it in product grid WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

I want to echo a list of the `product variations` in the `product grid` in `WooCommerce`.

For example on the shop page there is a product grid with product title + product description. After this I want to echo the product variations with the price.

The product is now like:

```
Product image
Product title
Product description
```

For example the product has two variations:

```
Kids € 12,00
Adults € 16,00
```

Then the product needs to be like:

```
Product image
Product title
Product description
Kids € 12,00
Adults € 16,00
```

Is there any hook for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;
    $variation_ids = $product->get_children();
    if( $variation_ids ) {
        foreach ( $variation_ids as $id ) {
            $v_product = wc_get_product($id);
            $variations = $v_product->get_variation_attributes();
            $variations_name = array();
            if( $variations ) {
                foreach ( $variations as $key => $value ) {
                    $variations_name[] = ucfirst( $value );
                }
            }
            echo '<p class="variation_price">'. implode( ', ', $variations_name ). " ". wc_price( $v_product->get_price() ).'</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

Comment: Hi, this is working but it echos the productname before it like `'productname' - 'variation' 'price'` I only want it to show it like `'variation' 'price'`

Comment: Also I want to wrap them into a element with class `<p class="variation_price"></p>`

Comment: Is it possible to show the regular price and sale price next to each other for a variation if there is a sale price?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Just replace `wc_price( $v_product->get_price() )` code with this `$v_product->get_price_html()`

Comment: It echos the name of the variation like the slug instead of the name. Can I change this. So for example now it shows `4-t-m-13-jaar` while it should be the name `4 t/m 13 jaar`